# Загрузка на хостинг некоторых папок из git-репозитория

Tags: git, github, gitlab

Имеется сайт на хостинге. Также имеется репозиторий на gitlab. Возможно ли на хостинг загружать только некоторые папки с репозитория?

Comment: А как происходит общение хостинга и gitlab?

Comment: При помощи gitlab-ci и всех вытекающих

Comment: Нужно просто написать скрипт, который соберет все нужные файлы в архив и выгрузит их на сервер. Правильный и надежный вариант

Answer (score 0):

Создаём 2 отдельных ветки под проект (`master`) и под его версию для хостинга (`hosting`). В каждой из веток находятся разные `.gitignore` файлы.
В основной ветке ведём всю историю. В `hosting` коммитим после каждого изменения master следующим образом (следует автоматизировать с помощью githook):

```
git checkout hosting
git cherry-pick -n master
git reset
git commit -m "Hosting-only changes"
```